# Find Missing records that are Not null

Tags: sql, notnull

I have two tables of account information. The 1st table **T1** has descriptions of all product lines along with submission number, name, region, status, policynumber and few more. The second table **T2** has only the information associated **only for Property line** along with its submission number, name region, status, policy number and others. Then column names are differently named in both the tables.

I need to **compare the two tables and find the missing policy numbers of the Property line in the second table T2**. I tried the below code and I get the list, yet I see the null values. How should I eliminate these null values from the result?

```
SELECT a.[Master Policy Number]
FROM   DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log AS a
WHERE 
    a.[Master Policy Number] NOT IN (
        SELECT b.PolNo
        FROM   DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files AS b
        WHERE  b.PolNo = a.[Master Policy Number]
            AND a.[Master Policy Number] IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: Don't you just want your Not In (Select b.PolNo... to be In (Select...?  You are saying where a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null) so you are finding ones that are null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `is not null` to outside the subquery. You already have an `=` condition in there that will exclude the nulls.

```
Select a.[Master Policy Number]
From   DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log a
Where  a.[Master Policy Number] Not In (Select b.PolNo
                                        From   DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files b
                                        Where  b.PolNo = a.[Master Policy Number])
And a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. What if I need to use more filters, do I need to use outside the subquery ?. Say in case, I need the Product subline also to be just "Property" and the status should be "Bound"

Comment: Yes, use the main query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.[Master Policy Number]
From   DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log a
Where  a.[Master Policy Number] Not In (Select b.PolNo
From   DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files b
Where  b.PolNo = a.[Master Policy Number]
) 
/* filter nulls on main query */ And a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out `NULL` values, then that filter should go in the *outer* query, not in the *inner* query:

```
Select a.[Master Policy Number]
From   DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log a
Where  a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null and
       a.[Master Policy Number] Not In (Select b.PolNo
                                        From DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files b
                                        Where  b.PolNo = a.[Master Policy Number]
                                       );
```

Oh, this is very strange.  You are comparing the same columns in for the `NOT IN` that are using in the correlation clause.  For that reason and the semantics of `NOT IN`, you should just use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

I should note that `NOT IN` with a subquery is dangerous.  If `b.PolNo` is *ever* `NULL`, then the `NOT IN` will never return true.  My recommendation is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
Select gsl.[Master Policy Number]
From DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log gsl
Where gsl.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files pf
                  where pf.PolNo = gsl.[Master Policy Number]
                 );
```

Note that I also think queries are easier to follow if the table aliases are abbreviations for the tables themselves.

Comment: You have an extra paren after `Is Not Null`

Answer (score 0):

If your result is the one that shows you the list of null, you could simply use `delete from` to delete the result.

`delete from DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log
Where [Master Policy Number] in
(
Select a.[Master Policy Number]From 
DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log a
Where  a.[Master Policy Number] Not In (Select b.PolNo From DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files b Where  b.PolNo = a.[Master Policy Number]
And a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null)
)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try left join ?

```
Select T1.[Master Policy Number] 
From  DB1.dbo.Global_Submission_Log T1 
LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.PROPERTY_Files T2 
ON T1.[Master Policy Number] on T2.PolNo 
Where  b.PolNo IS NULL
```

this will provide you the policy numbers that are not present in the Property_Files table but in Global_Submission table